# Angular JS and HTML query on dropdown hidden usages

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list of options for my dropDown in HTML i.e A, B, C, D, E, F.

I have three different tables on HTML page.
In table 1 I want to show a dropdown having options A, B and C.

In table 2 I want to show a dropdown having options A, B , D and F.

In table 3 I want to show a dropdown having options D and E.

I was using ng-repeat in my html to fetch option list and hidden tag.
like below.

```
ng-repeat="option in options"
            heading="{{option.name}}"
            hidden="option.hidden"
```

Now I am confused on how can I use hidden as single variable and display my options.

Can it be possible that I can use single options list and use it to display in my each table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you can replace the hidden with a list name that would solve it, in other words, you fetch the whole thing once and every option will have option.select value of list1, list2 or list3 and then you can display it as:

```
ng-repeat="option in options"
        heading="{{option.name}}"
        ng-if="option.select==list1"
```

(that's for the first select) and so on